# Solving a sign-constrained linear system

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces, linear-programming

Let ${\bf A}\in\mathbb{R}^{D\times D}$ and ${\bf b}\in [-1, 0, 1]^D$ be a binary vector. I am trying to solve:

$$\operatorname{sign}\left({\bf A}^\top {\bf x}\right) = {\bf b}.$$

What's the best approach to solving this problem? Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: don't you mean that $b \in \{-1,0,1\}^D$? If not, what do you mean by sign?

Comment: You are right, sorry for the typo!

Comment: Unless b=0 I don't think a minimum would generally exist. You can initially set X=0, then tip each of its components off from zero by a tiny amount to yield any sign vector sign(A^T x) you want. So X can get arbitrarily close to zero.

Comment: @Vim Very good point indeed! Thinking about it that way the norm minimisation is actually not so important and I am basically happy with any solution to the right-hand side (I am rewriting the problem now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $\text{sgn}(b)=b$, the solution of

$$Ax=b$$ is automatically such that $$\text{sgn}(Ax)=b.$$

Comment: I think the question is what to do if 'the' solution to $Ax=b$ does not exist

Comment: @LinAlg: I see nothing of that kind in the question.

Comment: Please excuse my late reply - your answer is absolutely correct! It also meant that my original idea for which I wanted to solve this problem didn't make sense in the first place ;-).

Comment: @user45893: no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let $i$ be the set of rows for which $b<0$, $j$ be the set of rows for which $b=0$ and $k$ be the set of rows for which $b>0$. You want to find an $x$ such that

$$A_i x \leq 1, A_j x = 0, A_k x \geq 1$$

The value 1 is chosen arbitrarily to obtain a closed set. It does not restrict the solution space, since if $A_i x < 0$, you can always scale $x$ such that $A_i x \leq 1$.

You can find an $x$ by solving the following linear optimization problem:
$$\min_{x}\{ 0 : A_i x \leq 1, A_j x = 0, A_k x \geq 1\},$$
for which many algorithms are available.